# i am getting need more than one value to unpack value error

Tags: python

This is my program

```
from sys import argv
script, first, second, third = argv
print ("the script is:", script)
print("the first variable is:", first)
print("the second variable is:", second)
print ("the third variable is:", third)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ravikishore/PycharmProjects/Test/.idea/MyPython.py", line 2, in <module>
    [script, first, second, third] = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: The duplicate I linked to is not only the same problem you're having, but it's the same exercise from the same tutorial.

Comment: As an aside, note that many Python programmers do _not_ recommend _Learn Python the Hard Way_.  It has [many problems](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints), and there are [better free tutorials](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) to choose from.  If you don't want to switch, at least remember that there _are_ other tutorials out there, so if a concept in _LPtHW_ doesn't make sense, you can read other explanations to see if they make more sense to you.

Answer (score 3):

`argv` is a list:

```
>>> from sys import argv
>>> type(argv)
<type 'list'>
```

So you're attempting to do a conversion from a list to a tuple, which only works if the number of elements in the tuple **exactly** matches the list length:

```
>>> a,b,c = [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>> a,b,c = [1,2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
>>> a,b,c = [1,2,3]
>>> a,b,c = [1,2,3,4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

So you need to add some checks on the `argv` length prior to attempting the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

That code works just *fine,* assuming that you actually *give* it three arguments to unpack, as with:

```
c:\pax> python yourProg.py A B C
the script is: yourProg.py
the first variable is: A
the second variable is: B
the third variable is: C
```

The problem occurs when you *don't* give it enough arguments:

```
c:\pax> python yourProg.py A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yourProg.py", line 2, in <module>
    script, first, second, third = argv
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```

If you want to ensure there are enough arguments before trying to unpack them, you can use `len(argv)` to get the argument count, and compare that to what you need, something like:

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("Need three arguments after script name")
    sys.exit(1)
script, first, second, third = sys.argv
print ("the script is:", script)
print("the first variable is:", first)
print("the second variable is:", second)
print ("the third variable is:", third)
```